# How to programmatically insert image into table cell and auto scale to fit

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-table

I automatically insert an image into a ms word document table cell. However.. I need to automatically scale the image (without losing dpi) to fit the table cell.
There are 2 table cells and they both supposed to take up 50% of the allocated width for the table. So.. as you can see... the image isnt scaled to fit the table cell. And the cells width arent equal. Basically the images are supposed to be placed in 2 columns with a blank row after each image row. For every 6th image a new page is inserted with a new table. Im posting an image and the code

[image: Image not scaling]

```
public void InsertTable()
        {
            List<string> pics = AmendPictures();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document WordDoc = null;         
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application axWord = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table axTable = null;
            try
            {              
                axWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                axWord.Visible = true;

                object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                WordDoc = axWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                // This is For Header columns 
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                int totalRows = (pics.Count % 2 == 0) ? pics.Count : (pics.Count + 1);
                int rowsPerTable = 6;
                int numberOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(totalRows/6)));

                int pageBreakCounter = 1;
                int y = 1;
                for (int x = 0; x < pics.Count; x += 2)
                {

                    if (((x % rowsPerTable) == 0) || (x ==0))
                    {
                        axWord.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast, oMissing, oMissing);
                        axTable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(axWord.Selection.Range, rowsPerTable, 2);
                        axTable.PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
                        axTable.PreferredWidth = 100;
                        axTable.AutoFitBehavior(WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow);
                        axTable.Range.Rows.Alignment = WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter;
                        axTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                        axTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0;
                        axTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0;
                        // Show Borders

                        axTable.Range.Columns.Borders.Enable = 1;

                        axTable.Columns[1].PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
                        axTable.Columns[1].SetWidth(50, WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);

                        axTable.Columns[2].PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
                        axTable.Columns[2].SetWidth(50, WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
                    }

                    InlineShape inline_shape = null;
                    InlineShape inline_shape2 = null;

                    Range rngPic1 = axTable.Cell((x+1) % 6, 1).Range;
                    rngPic1.Cells.VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
                    inline_shape = rngPic1.InlineShapes.AddPicture(pics.ElementAt(x).ToString(), ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                    if (inline_shape != null)
                    {
                        Shape shape = inline_shape.ConvertToShape();
                        shape.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapInline;
                    }

                    if ((x + 1) < pics.Count)
                    {
                        Range rngPic2 = axTable.Cell((x + 1) % 6, 2).Range;
                        rngPic2.Cells.VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
                        inline_shape2 = rngPic2.InlineShapes.AddPicture(pics.ElementAt(x+1).ToString(), ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                        if (inline_shape2 != null)
                        {
                            Shape shape = inline_shape2.ConvertToShape();
                            shape.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapInline;
                        }
                    }

                    pageBreakCounter++;

                    y = y + 2;
                    if ((x % rowsPerTable) == 0)
                    {
                        axWord.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast, oMissing, oMissing);
                        axWord.Selection.InsertNewPage();
                        y = 0;
                    }
                }
                WordDoc.Content.Font.Size = 12;
                WordDoc.Content.Font.Name = "Calibri";

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Dialog dialog = axWord.Dialogs[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileSaveAs];
                dialog.Show(ref oMissing);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "     " + ex.InnerException);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (axTable != null)
                {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(axTable);
                    // Release all Interop objects.
                }

                if (WordDoc != null)
                {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(WordDoc);
                }

                if (axWord != null)
                {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(axWord);
                }

                WordDoc = null;
                axWord = null;
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set either the row height or column width to an *exact* value, the image should scale to that dimension.

When doing this, also make sure the table auto fit behavior does not allow cell expansion. This means when adding a table set `DefaultTableBehavior` to `wdWord8TableBehavior`. And the `AutoFitBehavior` should be `wdAutoFitFixed`.

If a table already exists, the last can also be set specifically. In the code in the question I see that this is incorrect:

```
axTable.AutoFitBehavior(WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow);
```

You'll also need to test whether using percentage as the PreferredWidthType supports the exact settings. This may need to be changed to using Points.